# Windows Store Application Networking

Tags: c#, networking, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have created a windows store application that prints out network information using the using `Windows.Networking.Connectivity;` name space.

Although the application is running and working correctly, the [MegabytesUsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.dataplanusage.megabytesused.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) method is return "`Not Defined`". why is this.

Comment: Do you have the correct capabilities?

Comment: what do you mean by the correct capabilities

Comment: In your `Package.appxmanifest` file

Comment: i haven't changed the permissions in the manifest

Comment: i only have this inside the capabilities tag <Capability Name="internetClient" />

Comment: Can it be that you have not enabled the data usage in the settings for the network? Charms -> Settings -> Computer settings -> Networks -> YourNetwork?

Comment: I have just enabled the estimated data usage, but its staying at 0.00 MB

Comment: Then the problem is probably your specific computer.

Comment: how would i go about fixing this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app in Local Machine and you are connected with ethernet you dont use DataPlan.

If you want to debug open with Simulator and enable "Use simulated network prperties" and then change Data Limit Status Flag and you will see results.

```
ConnectionProfile profile =  NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
DataPlanStatus dps = profile .GetDataPlanStatus() ;
textBlock.Text =  dps.DataPlanUsage.MegabytesUsed.ToString();
```